# What kind of taxes were inns/taverns expected to pay in France and the Holy Roman Empire during the 1300-1500?

Tags: middle-ages, taxes

As the headline suggests, I am interested in what kind of taxes were paid from the owners of inns/taverns (since those 2 were often one and the same). The period and region I am most interested in are France and Germany's 14th and 15th centuries. The two related articles on [inns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inn) and [taverns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tavern) make little mention on taxes. One mention is the wine tax used in France after the 1500s. Where additional taxes levied on food served and rooms rented? Who collected them and what efforts were made to avoid fraud?

Comment: I doubt the question has an answer. neither France nor HRE had a coherent tax policy.  Even the French didn't understand French taxes - I think someone once wrote that there were were more than ten thousand tax boundaries in France, and each type of tax had different boundaries.   The taxes wouldn't depend on "France", but on the overlapping set of particular tax departments in which that tavern was located.  (plus corruption), I regret I can't recall my source, but perhaps that will help your research.

Comment: "Under the Old Regime, the collection of taxes was leased, i.e. that the state entrusted the task to entrepreneurs, big farmers, who paid the amount of the tax to be levied, then levied the tax for themselves. The system was convenient for both the state (the revenue was anticipated and it was disposed of the unpopularity of tax collectors) and for big farmers (the bargain was very profitable). However, the people considered the collection mainly a source of injustice and excesses." _[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxation_in_France#History_of_taxes_in_France_)

Comment: @MCW interesting. So the state expected a fixed sum from the tax collectors and then it was up to the collectors to turn a profit from this activity? Did they impose any tax they wanted?

Comment: Beyond my expertise & knowledge.  Might research Roman tax farming.  Might examine the hypothesis that the goal was to raise revenue, rather than a modern cohere fair policy framework